# modular arithmetic in rolling hash algorithm

Tags: modular-arithmetic, rolling-hash

My question was around the rolling hash function in [RobinKarp algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wsgUh0w49Nc). It is intuitive for me to understand how to get from xi to xi+1 without the mod, however with the mod i am not sure how we still get the right answer. Is there any mathematical theroem anyone could quote which would help me understand?

So i get,

```
xi = (ti)R^0 + (ti+1)R^1 + .. + (ti+m-1)R^M-1
xi+1 = (xi - (ti)R^0)/R + (ti+m)R^M
```

but whats the guarantee,

```
xi = [ (ti)R^0 + (ti+1)R^1 + .. + (ti+m-1)R^M-1 ] mod Q
xi+1 = [ (xi - (ti)R^0)/R + (ti+m)R^M ] mod Q
```

.. and so on will be correct even after introducing mod Q

Pretty sure its some basic mod arithmetic theorem i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the identity
$$
(a + b) \bmod{Q} = (a \bmod{Q} + b \bmod{Q}) \bmod{Q}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The video actually does it the other way around, kicking out the term with the highest power and then multiplying by R. It turns out to not really make a difference, but this is clearly always possible regardless of whether modular arithmetic is used or not.

Going back to what you wrote though. Without the modular arithmetic, the division by R is possible because the dividend is a multiple of R (it was carefully constructed to be).

With the modular arithmetic, the division by R is possible because R and Q are chosen such that $\gcd(R, Q) = 1$, therefore R has a modular multiplicative inverse modulo Q and can *always* be divided by. As a bonus, dividing by R becomes a multiplication, which is easier than integer division even if it is by a constant.